# Convert to string in Postman?

Tags: json, string, postman, postman-collection-runner

In Postman, I use `{{$randomUUID}}` as a parameter, but I need to pass it as string (text) in the request. However, there is no convert function in Postman and I could not found any proper way to convert this generated UUID to string.  So, how can I convert it to string in Postman and pass it as string?

I also tried something like `"menuId":  {{"" + $randomUUID}},`, but is does not work.

Comment: Does anybody else using Postman?

Comment: Check if this would help:https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-convert-integer-value-to-string-while-in-pre-request-script/16311

convert the value for randomUUID to string in pre-request and then use it as a the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{

"menuId": "{{$randomUUID}}"

}
```

you just have to enclose it with double quotes